# Encapsulating snprintf to avoid repetition of sizeof

Tags: c, formatting, macros, variadic, gcc

Correct usage of `snprintf` involves very long and repetitive lines:

```c
if (snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), format, ...) >= (int)sizeof(buff))
        goto err;
```

I first encapsulated this macro: `#define SSIZEOF(x) ((ssize_t)sizeof(x))`.  The result is I now have a slightly shorter line:

```c
if (snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), format, ...) >= SSIZEOF(buff))
        goto err;
```

But I'm not yet happy.  Writing `sizeof` twice is still very long and annoying, and more if the buffer has a relatively long name.

I decided to do a macro that behaves this way (with the same exact safety) (The `b` in the name stands for buffer):

```c
if (sbprintf(buff, format, ...))
        goto err;
```

It needs to be a macro to avoid the array decaying to a pointer, so that I can still use `sizeof(buff)` inside the macro.

---

`sbprintf.h`:

```c
/******************************************************************************
 ******* include guard ********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
#ifndef ALX_STDIO_SBPRINTF_H
#define ALX_STDIO_SBPRINTF_H


/******************************************************************************
 ******* headers **************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
#include <stdio.h>

#include "libalx/base/assert/assert.h"
#include "libalx/base/compiler/size.h"


/******************************************************************************
 ******* macros ***************************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
/* int  sbprintf(char buff[restrict], const char *restrict format, ...); */
#define sbprintf(buff, format, ...)     (                               \
{                                                                       \
        alx_static_assert_array(buff);                                  \
                                                                        \
        snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), format, ##__VA_ARGS__) >= SSIZEOF(buff) \
}                                                                       \
)


/******************************************************************************
 ******* include guard ********************************************************
 ******************************************************************************/
#endif      /* libalx/base/stdio/sbprintf.h */
```

Used macros (defined in other headers from my library (libalx)):

```c
#include <assert.h>

#include <sys/types.h>


#define alx_same_type(a, b) __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(a), typeof(b))

#define alx_static_assert_array(a)      do                              \
{                                                                       \
        static_assert(!alx_same_type((a), &(a)[0]), "Not an array!");   \
} while (0)

#define SSIZEOF(x)      ((ssize_t)sizeof(x))
```

---

I use GCC8 and C17 (`gcc -std=gnu17 -Wall -Wextra -Werror`), but if there is any easy and not very ugly fix that helps portability, it is welcome.  The same about C++:  This is about C (I'll ask the same question about C++ after this one has been answered), but if there is any fix that would improve compatibility with C++, it is also welcome.

What do you think about `sbprintf`?  Feel free to comment the other macros, of course!

**EDIT:**

The actual name of the macro in my library is `alx_sbprintf` to avoid using a name that may end up being used by a future implementation.

---

Related links:

- [How to make a variadic macro (variable number of arguments)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/679993/6872717)

Comment: I'm looking forward to seeing the C++ equivalent - I anticipate that we won't need macros for that.

Comment: @TobySpeight Really? For arrays (`char []`) (not vectors or weird things)? I was thinking of using macros, but that sounds interesting.

Comment: I'm pretty sure C++ templates provide all we need (and we can be specific that we what a `char` array, rather than any other kind, if we want).

Comment: Related: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/212271/macro-for-allocation-in-c

Comment: @TobySpeight C++: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/223372/200418

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good and useful idea.  The name is intuitive and memorable.

My first thought was that if a pointer were passed, then we'd use the size of the pointer, but you've found a good way to ensure only arrays are passed.

Obviously, this means that we can't use this for those occasions where we build up the content in pieces (with several prints into a larger array), but that's less common than having a plain `char[]` we're allowed to fill, so it's probably reasonable to require callers to use `snprintf()` directly in those cases.

Although I'd probably provide `SSIZEOF(x)`, I wouldn't depend on it in `sbprintf()` - there's no great overhead to writing it in full here.

Although we normally enclose macro arguments in `()` to prevent higher-precedence operators tearing expressions apart, I think you're right that it's not needed for the first use of `buff`, where it's a single argument to a function call.  I don't *think* there's a valid use where `sizeof` would break an expression of array type, but I'm willing to be defensive there.

One concern is that we now get a boolean result, but have lost the actual number of characters written, necessitating a call to `strlen()` if we need the length (e.g. to compose a network protocol packet).  It might be possible to write a version that also stores the actual length written:

```
/* untested */
#define sbprintf(buff, written, format, ...)                            \
    ( {                                                                 \
        alx_static_assert_array(buff);                                  \
                                                                        \
        (*written = snprintf(buff,sizeof(buff),format, ##__VA_ARGS__))  \
            >= (int)sizeof(buff)                                        \
            } )
```

Of course, a really usable version of this would allow `written` to be a null pointer, to discard the result.  That's not hard, but I'm feeling too lazy to write that myself.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I wrote it (see my answer) :)

Comment: I'd suggest performing instead an _unsigned_ compare than `*written ... >= (int)sizeof(buff)` as [discussed](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/223179/29485).

Comment: What do you think would be better to store in `written`: the output of `snprintf` or the actual length of the string? I think the actual length, but have some doubts.

Comment: @chux, agreed; @ cacahuete, good question, and there are arguments for both (I'll sit on the fence!)

Comment: @CacahueteFrito Set aside type concerns: consider value: With `sbprintf(buff, written, "%c%c%c", 'a', 0, 'b')`  Do you want the return value of `snprintf()` or "the actual length of the string"

Comment: @chux My thoughts: The theoretical value that would have been printed if there had been enough space isn't very useful (it's main use is reporting truncation, and we already have that). The length of the string can only be calculated by using `strlen`, and that would be heavy; also, the case that someone prints a NUL in a buffer and still wants to use it as a string is, at least, rare. The third option is the actual number of characters written, which is the return value of `snprintf` truncated by `sizeof(buff) - 1`. That one is simple to get, and I think the most useful.

Comment: @CacahueteFrito Re: Option 3: If the value returned included the written append _null character_, then a return of 0 is error. Useful, yet a different-by-1 paradigm.  IAC, good documentation that reflects these corner cases is important.

Comment: @chux Please, rephrase the first sentence; I didn't fully understand it.  Yes, IAC it needs to be documented

Comment: @CacahueteFrito e.g. `sbprintf(s,3,"ab")` --> 3. `sbprintf(s,3,"")` --> 1. `sbprintf(s,3,"abc")` --> 0 (error). `sbprintf(s,3,"ab")` with encoding error --> 0.  return of 0 implies error, else number (`size_t`) of characters written (including the append null character).

Comment: @chux Aside: the `3` isn't needed: `char s[3];` `sbprintf(s, "ab") == 3`, `sbprintf(s, "abc") == 0` ... .  Good idea.  Problems: Now we loose information about the type of error: if it was an error, or just truncation; we need to check `errno` against `ENOMEM`.  More complicated: Usage if we want to use the buffer even if truncated: `w = sbprintf(b, "ab"); if (!w && (errno != ENOMEM)) {goto err;}` vs `if (sbprintf(b, &w, "ab") < 0) {goto err;}`.  Usage if we don't want to use the buffer if truncated: `w = sbprintf(b, "ab"); if (!w) {goto err;}` vs `if (sbprintf(b, &w, "ab")) {goto err;}`.

Comment: How would `ENOMEM` occur?  There's no allocations involved.

Comment: @TobySpeight I set `ENOMEM` on truncation (see my answer). If you think there's another `errno` value more adecuate, please tell me. `EOVERFLOW` was my other candidate, but `snprintf` already uses it, so I thought that a different one would be better.  Would you prefer `EOVERFLOW`?

Comment: Ah, I thought you were discussing *this* answer or the question.  It's confusing when comments range across several answers; sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

Pedantically, `if (snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), format, ...) >= SSIZEOF(buff)) goto err;` is an insufficient test.  Test for `< 0` is also needed.

> The `snprintf` function returns the number of characters that would have been written
>   had `n` been sufficiently large, not counting the terminating null character, or a negative value if an encoding error occurred....
>   C111 §7.21.6.5 3

---

Note that `ssize_t` itself is not in standard C.

---

To cope with both issues, perform 2 sided test and drop using `ssize_t`.

```
int i = snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), format, ...);
if (i < 0 || (unsigned) i >= sizeof(buff)) goto err;
```

... or if `INT_MAX <= UINT_MAX/2` (a **very** common implementation), code can cheat with a one sided test as `i<0` coverts to a large `unsigned`.  Again no need for `ssize_t`.

```
int i = snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), format, ...);
if ((unsigned) i >= sizeof(buff)) goto err;
```

Comment: True, I thought about it once and discarded adding that to my code because it would mean adding a variable and many lines, but now that it is inside a macro it is doable :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that **Toby Speight** suggested in his answer:

```c
/*
 * int  sbprintf(char buff[restrict], int *restrict written,
 *                              const char *restrict format, ...);
 */
#define sbprintf(buff, written, format, ...)    (                       \
{                                                                       \
        int     len_;                                                   \
                                                                        \
        alx_static_assert_array(buff);                                  \
                                                                        \
        len_    = snprintf((buff), sizeof(buff), format, ##__VA_ARGS__);\
        if (written != NULL)                                            \
                *written = len_;                                        \
        len_ >= (int)sizeof(buff);                                      \
}                                                                       \
)
```

---

I have tested it and works as expected:

- If `written` is `NULL` it doesn't write into it.
- The return value is `true` when the string is truncated and `false` otherwise.
- It doesn't compile if `buff` is not an array.
- It accepts a variable number of arguments after `format`, including no arguments.

The comment above the macro is the prototype that a user should see, to better understand the usage, although a real function with that prototype wouldn't work because of the array decaying to a pointer.

---

Comments about the style:

I tried to follow the Linux Kernel Coding Style, but there have been exceptions:

`if (written != NULL)` is used instead of `if (written)` to avoid the compiler complaining:

```
main.c:22:23: error: the address of ‘w1’ will always evaluate as ‘true’ [-Werror=address]
  if (alx_sbprintf(b1, &w1, test))
                       ^
.../libalx/base/stdio/sbprintf.h:36:6: note: in definition of macro ‘alx_sbprintf’
  if (written)       \
      ^~~~~~~
```

---

**EDIT:**

Given that `snprintf` sets `errno` (at least in [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/snprintf.html)), it would be good to set `errno` to `ENOMEM` on truncation.

---

**EDIT:**

This version includes the improvements suggested by **Toby Speight** and  **chux**, as well as setting `errno` on error.  First I added code to the macro, but it proved to have [some problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56825271/6872717) (at least it didn't compile, so no dangerous bugs).  Now it's an `extern` function enclosed in a simple macro.

Now the code relies less on GCC extensions.

Properties:

- If `written` is `NULL` it doesn't write into it.
- It doesn't compile if `buff` is not an array.
- It accepts a variable number of arguments after `format`, including no arguments.
- Sets `errno` on any error.
- If there's a `snprintf` internal error, the error code is negative (`-errno`), and `written` is also negative.
- If the string is truncated, the error code is positive (`ENOMEM`).
- If the error code is negative, the string should not be trusted;  if it's positive, it's been truncated, but it's a valid string.

Code:

`sbprintf.h`:

```c
#ifndef ALX_STDIO_PRINTF_SBPRINTF_H
#define ALX_STDIO_PRINTF_SBPRINTF_H


#include "libalx/base/assert/assert.h"
#include "libalx/base/stdio/printf/swnprintf.h"


/*
 * int  sbprintf(char buff[restrict], ptrdiff_t *restrict written,
 *              const char *restrict format, ...);
 */
#define sbprintf(buff, written, fmt, ...)   (                           \
{                                                                       \
                                                                        \
        alx_static_assert_array(buff);                                  \
        swnprintf(buff, written, sizeof(buff), fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__);     \
}                                                                       \
)


#endif      /* libalx/base/stdio/printf/sbprintf.h */
```

`swnprintf.h`:

```c
#ifndef ALX_STDIO_PRINTF_SWNPRINTF_H
#define ALX_STDIO_PRINTF_SWNPRINTF_H


#include <stddef.h>


int     swnprintf(char str[restrict], ptrdiff_t *restrict written, ptrdiff_t nmemb,
                        const char *restrict format, ...);


#endif      /* libalx/base/stdio/printf/swnprintf.h */
```

`swnprintf.c`:

```c
#include "libalx/base/stdio/printf/swnprintf.h"

#include <errno.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int     swnprintf(char str[restrict], ptrdiff_t *restrict written, ptrdiff_t nmemb,
                        const char *restrict format, ...)
{
        va_list ap;
        int     len;

        if (nmemb < 0)
                goto neg;

        va_start(ap, format);
        len     = vsnprintf(str, nmemb, format, ap);
        va_end(ap);

        if (written != NULL)
                *written = len;

        if (len < 0)
                goto err;
        if (len >= nmemb)
                goto trunc;

        return  0;
trunc:
        if (written)
                *written = nmemb - 1;
        errno   = ENOMEM;
        return  ENOMEM;
neg:
        errno   = EOVERFLOW;
err:
        if (written)
                *written = 0;
        return  -errno;
}
```

**Edit:**

Modified to use `ptrdiff_t`: it allows to detect invalid (negative) sizes, instead of using their unsigned value.  Also removes a cast.

Modified to set `written` to 0 on error when the string is unreliable.

---

The return value should **always** be used:

```
__attribute__((warn_unused_result))
```

Add checks to the format and varargs:

```
__attribute__((format(printf, 4, 5)))
```

**EDIT:**

When using `__attribute__((warn_unused_result))`, the macro `sbprintf` silences the warning because of the way it works;  to warn the user, the following code can be used:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE(a)       (sizeof(a) / sizeof((a)[0]))

#define sbprintf(buff, written, fmt, ...)                               \
        swnprintf(buff, written, ARRAY_SIZE(buff), fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

Note:  GCC 8 warns (`-Werror=sizeof-pointer-div`) if buff is not an array without needing a `static_assert`, when using `ARRAY_SIZE` defined this way.  If using an old version of GCC, you will need to use some tricks to block compilation.

Comment: 1: Does the macro "return" anything? Do you want `,` instead of `;`? 2: Consider `(unsigned) len_ >= sizeof(buff)`

Comment: @chux 1: Of course macros don't return, but compound statements simulate that return value.  That's why I said *"return"*.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html  I didn't want `,`, a `;` works fine (I assume you meant after the last statement).

Comment: The "return" is a gcc thing,  per your link, a C extension that I was unaware. I suspect a C compliant version is possible

Comment: @chux Oh, now I understand what you meant. In this case, I prefer to use the extension; I think it's more reliable than the comma, I think: I can use almost anything and will work (`__auto_type`, `goto`, ...). The comma has too many different meanings, so I don't trust it very much. I'll add the code I have with errno and goto so that you can see what I mean.